# How to stop a clone from inheriting a message

Tags: mit-scratch

I have this code:

[image: code]

But whenever the **shoot** message is sent to the **bullet** sprite, and there is a clone on the stage that hasn't hit it's target yet, the clone will be sent back with the `go to x: (xOfTower) y: (yOfTower)` block. Is there some way to prevent a clone from receiving a message while the real sprite does?

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" to the question title. If an answer is helpful to you, you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) and/or [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) the answer. Note however that you are not obliged to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Clones have their own copy of local variables!**

To solve this problem you can add a new variable but be sure to check 'For this sprite only'. Otherwise there will only be 1 variable.

[image]

Now a new variable will be created for each clone. Give the variable a value to label it as clone and add a guard on your message action.

[image: scratch code]

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prevent all sprites receiving the broadcast message. You have to write code to make those that shouldn't act on it, ignore it. In this case I suggest it is easier to do the following:

Suggest moving the two lines

```
point in direction (directionOfTower)
go to x: (xOfTower) y: (yOfTower)
```

into the `when I start as clone` block.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. It has been a while since I have done Scratch but I remember that clones have variables, so if you give a clone a variable (something like: isClone) and then inside the messages it is inheriting have an if statement at the top so everything else runs if it is true. Then the if statement if set up correctly should check if isClone is equal to 0 and then if so then run the broadcast. The way you give clones variables is through inheritance because they inherit variables, if you change a variable inside a clone script then it will change the variable only for that clone and not the parent sprite or any other clone.

Comment: Also has to be for this sprite only